# AWK script: Finding number of matches that each element in Col2 has in Col1

Tags: linux, macos, awk

I want to compare two columns in a file as below using AWK, can someone gives a help please?

e.g.

```
Col1   Col2
----   ----
 2      A
 2      D
 3      D
 3      D
 3      A
 7      N
 7      M
 1      D
 1      R
```

Now I want to use AWK to implement the following algorithm to find matches between those columns:

```
list1[] <=== Col1
list2[] <=== Col2
NewList[]
for i in col2:
   d = 0
   for j in range(1,len(col2)):
      if i == list2[j]: 
         d++
   NewList.append(list1[list2.index[i]])
```

Expected result:

```
A ==> 2  // means A matches two times to Col1
D ==> 4  // means D matches two times to Col1
....
```

So I want to write the above code in AWK script and I find it too complicated for me as I haven't used it yet.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: So basically you just want a count of each letter in col2? Or am I totally misunderstanding the question? Also I must say, not making an effort because it's too complicated doesn't usually make people here rush to help.

Comment: please remove the `python` tag because the question is not about python and will attract people who are out to help on python.

Comment: If you want us to help you write the awk code to implement an algorithm then show that algorithm in simple pseudo-code that everyone can understand, not a segment of code from some other language. Unless you're only interested in getting awk help from python (or whatever that is) experts, of course, but then YMMV wrt the quality of the awk script you end up with. I'm pretty decent with awk and I expect I could create an equivalent python script given a small awk script but I wouldn't recommend you use it in a live product:-)!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks, yes exactly like you said I need the count of each letter in Col2, e.g. there four D in Col2. Can you help me doing that in AWK?

Comment: @EdMorton, As Joachim said, I need counts of each letter in Col2. Thanks for your help too. By the way, I only use this AWK code for data processing purposes not in a live product :) so I expect it to be much faster than Python or other languages.

Comment: I don't understand `A ==> 2  // means A matches two times to Col1`.  How does `Col1` fit into this?

Comment: @jas that means you can find two "A"s in Col1 ;)

Comment: Sorry to be so thick, but I don't see any "A"s in Col1, only numbers!

Comment: :) the easiest way to re-ask the question, I want to see how many As in Col2, and how many Ds in Col2... etc.

Comment: Does `Col1` have **anything** at all to do with your question???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all that complicated, keep the count in an array indexed by the character and print the array out at the end;

```
awk '{cnt[$2]++} END {for(c in cnt) print c, cnt[c]}' test.txt

# A 2
# D 4
# M 1
# N 1
# R 1

{cnt[$2]++}  # For each row, get the second column and increase the
             # value of the array at that position (ie cnt['A']++)

END {for(c in cnt) print c, cnt[c]}
             # When all rows done (END), loop through the keys of the
             # array and print key and array[key] (the value)
```

Comment: Just curious: why the redirect instead of just the file-name?

Comment: @tink Not an intentional thing, just old habit. Either works fine :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks man. I tested it. A file above million rows, took 4-5 seconds :) that is why I love awk.

Comment: Don't use the input redirection thing as it's not extensible to 2 or more input files and it robs awk of it's ability to use `FILENAME`.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point. I'm just a pipe kind of guy, so by old habit I tend to use redirection when possible to not have things break when I change to using a pipe :) Updated the answer to use the file name.

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution

```
$ rev file | cut -c1 | sort | uniq -c

  2 A
  4 D
  1 M
  1 N
  1 R
```

for the formatting pipe to `... | sed -r 's/(\w) (\w)/\2 ==> \1/'`

```
  A ==> 2
  D ==> 4
  M ==> 1
  N ==> 1
  R ==> 1
```

Or, do everything in `awk`

Comment: I tried your solution, it doesn't work to me too me. It just sums all the rows at the end. that is all it does.

Comment: That's what I understood from your post.  First column seems irrelevant. For the count of `A`s `D`s etc.  `sort | uniq -c` is the standard solution, the rest is just scaffolding.